# Spring Boot Integration - Send greet on connection initialization

Tags: java, spring-boot, tcp, spring-integration, tcplistener

I am writing a simple TCP Server application with Spring Boot Integration Framework that has to send a greeting to the client on connection establishment. The workflow should be as follows:

1. Client connects to server
2. Server sends a greeting message to the client "Hello client"
3. Client sends a message to the server "Any string"
4. Server responds with "OK"
5. ...

Currently steps 1, 3 and 4 are working, but I'm failing on step 2.
My code so far:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableIntegration
public class ExampleApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExampleApp.class, args);
    }

    // Create listener on port 1234
    @Bean
    public AbstractServerConnectionFactory serverConnectionFactory() {
        TcpNetServerConnectionFactory tcpNetServerConnectionFactory = new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(1234);
        return tcpNetServerConnectionFactory;
    }

    // Inbound channel
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel requestChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    // Outbound channel
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel replyChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    // Inbound gateway
    @Bean
    public TcpInboundGateway tcpInboundGateway(AbstractServerConnectionFactory serverConnectionFactory, MessageChannel requestChannel, MessageChannel replyChannel) {
        TcpInboundGateway tcpInboundGateway = new TcpInboundGateway();
        tcpInboundGateway.setConnectionFactory(serverConnectionFactory);
        tcpInboundGateway.setRequestChannel(requestChannel);
        tcpInboundGateway.setReplyChannel(replyChannel);
        return tcpInboundGateway;
    }

    // Send reply for incoming message -> working
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "requestChannel", outputChannel = "replyChannel")
    public Message<String> processMessage(Message<String> message) {
        Message reply = MessageBuilder
                .withPayload("OK")
                .setHeader(IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID, message.getHeaders().get(IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID, String.class))
                .build();
        return reply;
    }

    // Send greeting -> not working
    @Bean
    public ApplicationListener<TcpConnectionEvent> listener(MessageChannel replyChannel) {
        return tcpConnectionEvent -> {
            if (tcpConnectionEvent instanceof TcpConnectionOpenEvent) {
                Message<String> message = MessageBuilder
                        .withPayload("Hello client")
                        .setHeader(IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID, tcpConnectionEvent.getConnectionId())
                        .build();
                replyChannel.send(message);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

If I connect to the server with

```
nc -C localhost 1234
```

connection is established, but I'm getting the following error in the log:

> Failed to publish TcpConnectionOpenEvent [source=TcpNetConnection:localhost:37656:1234:187cfbc2-7e5d-4f4e-97de-1a3b55a4e264], [factory=serverConnectionFactory, connectionId=localhost:37656:1234:187cfbc2-7e5d-4f4e-97de-1a3b55a4e264] **OPENED**:Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.replyChannel'

If I send a String to the server he replies with "OK" as intended.

What am I missing to get this greeting message working?

## Solution

Thanks to the comment of Gary Russel I found a solution. The Inbound gateway must be "split" into a Inbound/Outbound channel adapter pair. Here is the fully working example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableIntegration
public class ExampleApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExampleApp.class, args);
    }

    // Create listener on port 1234
    @Bean
    public AbstractServerConnectionFactory serverConnectionFactory() {
        TcpNetServerConnectionFactory tcpNetServerConnectionFactory = new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(1234);
        return tcpNetServerConnectionFactory;
    }

    // Inbound channel
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel requestChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    // Outbound channel
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel replyChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    // Inbound channel adapter
    @Bean
    public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter receivingChannelAdapter(AbstractServerConnectionFactory serverConnectionFactory, MessageChannel requestChannel) {
        TcpReceivingChannelAdapter tcpReceivingChannelAdapter = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
        tcpReceivingChannelAdapter.setConnectionFactory(serverConnectionFactory);
        tcpReceivingChannelAdapter.setOutputChannel(requestChannel);
        return tcpReceivingChannelAdapter;
    }

    // Outbound channel adapter
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "replyChannel")
    public TcpSendingMessageHandler tcpSendingMessageHandler(AbstractServerConnectionFactory serverConnectionFactory) {
        TcpSendingMessageHandler tcpSendingMessageHandler = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
        tcpSendingMessageHandler.setConnectionFactory(serverConnectionFactory);
        return tcpSendingMessageHandler;
    }

    // Send reply for incoming message -> working
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "requestChannel", outputChannel = "replyChannel")
    public Message<String> processMessage(Message<String> message) {
        Message<String> reply = MessageBuilder
                .withPayload("OK")
                .setHeader(IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID, message.getHeaders().get(IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID, String.class))
                .build();
        return reply;
    }

    // Send greeting -> now working
    @Bean
    public ApplicationListener<TcpConnectionEvent> listener(MessageChannel replyChannel) {
        return tcpConnectionEvent -> {
            if (tcpConnectionEvent instanceof TcpConnectionOpenEvent) {
                Message<String> message = MessageBuilder
                        .withPayload("Hello client")
                        .setHeader(IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID, tcpConnectionEvent.getConnectionId())
                        .build();
                replyChannel.send(message);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Now the client gets the greeting "Hello client" on connection establishment and an "OK" as reply on each send message.

Comment: above error suggests that replyChannel has no subscriber, So you can bridge the replyChannel with a null channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> replyChannel.send(message);

You can't do that; the reply channel is wired up when the first request comes in.

In any case, you can't use a gateway like that, the reply channel is for a reply to a request not for sending some arbitrary message.

You have to use a pair of inbound/outbound channel adapters, instead of a gateway, to enable arbitrary two-way communication.

Comment: Thanks, your comment pushed me into the right direction.

Comment: You don't need @EnableIntegration. Boot sets that when it detects the core integration jar on the class path.